# ScintillaNET : Regex keywords, non-alphanumerical keywords

Tags: .net, regex, scintilla

I'd first like to know if it's possible to include keyword containing non-alphanumerical characters? Like `@help` or `+test`

Second, is it possible to use regex or wildcards with keywords? Like I'd like to color matches for `@\w*`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Wow... no one has answered this in over a year? The answer is yes... you can. I don't know scintilla, but most regex engines allow you to use a backslash to "escape" the character:

```regex
\@help
\+test
```

I've recently encountered a case where the regex engine does not allow escaping of all special characters. In that case, you can usually enclose the character within square brackets:

```regex
[@]help
[+]test
```

I'd wish you luck, but you've probably already figured this out or moved on at this point.